# Wait on multiple Conditions in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I want a thread to wait until any of two [Condition](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html)s are signaled.
Is it possible?

Suppose the thread is handling incoming packets of data, while it's possible a user interrupts by changing some states.

One Condition is signaled when a packet has come, and the other is signaled when states have been changed.

I think it's inappropriate to use one Condition for both events, because that would cause a lot of unnecessary wakeups in other threads which are monitoring the states.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a third condition that is signaled by both incoming packets and user state changes?  I don't think it is possible to wait on multiple conditions.

Comment: So every signaling thread signals twice (`packetCond.signalAll(); packetOrStatesCond.signalAll();`)? Far from elegant, but it worked anyway. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a semaphore, with 2 permits, have your waiting item acquire those 2, and have your events release those permits, 1 at a time until 2 are back?

Comment: That gives you *both of two* conditions.  The OP wants *either of two* conditions.